# Why does rand() yield the same sequence of numbers on every run?

Tags: c++, random

Every time I run a program with `rand()` it gives me the same results.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int random (int low, int high) {
    if (low > high)
        return high;
    return low + (rand() % (high - low + 1));
}

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << random (2, 5) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3
5
4
2
3
```

Each time I run the program it outputs the same numbers every time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Actually, behavior seems to have been reversed at some point.  I cannot get the same sequence *unless* I call `srand()` with the same argument.  Without calling `srand()` the sequence does not repeat.  That with gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The seed for the random number generator is not set.

If you call `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))` then you will get more random results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    cout << rand() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The reason is that a random number generated from the `rand()` function isn't actually random.  It simply is a transformation.  Wikipedia gives a better explanation of the meaning of pseudorandom number generator:  deterministic random bit generator.  Every time you call `rand()` it takes the seed and/or the last random number(s) generated (the C standard doesn't specify the algorithm used, though C++11 has facilities for specifying some popular algorithms), runs a mathematical operation on those numbers, and returns the result.  So if the seed state is the same each time (as it is if you don't call `srand` with a truly random number), then you will always get the same 'random' numbers out.

If you want to know more, you can read the following:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24225-random-number-generation-102/

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/29294-making-pseudo-random-number-generators-more-random/

Comment: What if I have the function in an .h file? Where is the appropriate place to set the seed if not in main?

Comment: You could set it in the constructor of an object that you know will be constructed before `rand()` is first called (e.g. in a static/singleton object if necessary)

Answer (score 21):

If you call `rand()` without first calling `srand()`, it will act as if you have called `srand(1)` implicitly. The relevant bit of the standard `C99 7.20.2.2 The srand function` (on which `cstdlib` is based) states:

> If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1.

In other words, you *will* get the same sequence each time. You can change your `main` into:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    srand (time (0));  // needs ctime header.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << random (2, 5) << endl;
    wait ();
}
```

to fix this, assuming you don't run it more than once a second.

As mentioned, you'll need the `ctime` header for this. You should also be pulling in `cstdlib` since that's where `rand` and `srand` live. It's also usually a good idea to use the `cXXX` headers rather than the `XXX.h` ones (`cmath` rather than `math.h`, for example).

So, having made *all* those changes (and using explicit namespaces, which I prefer though others may not), I'd end up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

void wait () {
    int e;
    std::cin >> e;
}

int random (int low, int high) {
    if (low > high) return high;
    return low + (std::rand() % (high - low + 1));
}

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    std::srand (std::time (0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << random (2, 5) << '\n';
    wait ();
}
```

which gives a different sequence each time I run it, for a few times anyway. Obviously, there's a hard limit on when the data will repeat (there are only 4<sup>5</sup> possibilities) and the "random" nature of the output means it may repeat before then as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

That's a feature of the `rand()` function.

What you have is not a random number generator, but more strictly a *["pseudorandom number generator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)*. Being able to reproduce the same random sequences for the same seed (you seed using the `srand(x)` function) can be important to reproduce bugs or to preserve state across program runs.

Personally, I use this feature to be able to pause/persist rendering-processes in a [Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)-based terrain renderer. A nice side effect is that you are able to guarantee different Monte Carlo experiments on different machines, and therefore be able to generate guaranteed different results that can then be reduced in a final step to a higher quality end result (of course you can later reuse this higher quality end result to produce even higher quality results).

Note, however, that neither C nor C++ define the number sequence from `rand()`. So if you need guaranteed sequences across platforms, use one of C++11's new random number generators (e.g. a [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)), roll your own (some generators are almost trivial to grasp, however, because most of them rely on specific overflow behaviour their implementation might not be trivial), or use a third-party component (e.g. boost::random).

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the random number generator (see the function 'srand'). Assuming you aren't doing cryptography, then seeding it with the output of 'time' is probably good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting psuedo random numbers. To make them "more random" you can seed the random number generator using something that "changes" (most commonly the current time).

Comment: Nit: Mathematically, that won't make them "more random".

Comment: True, but in the context of the OP's question... (plus it's in quotes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses a pseudorandom number generator. Essentially, that means that your program is reading off an extremely long list of pre-determined numbers. When you repeatedly run your program, it gives the same numbers each time because it is reading from the beginning of that list of numbers each time.

You can set your program to start at the nth number on the list. You can use the time or the temperature or anything else that's "random". (For temperature, you could take the last digit of the temperature, or use the decimal places after it.)

Answer (score -1):

Use randomize(). It automatically seeds the value.
Or if you want to use rand() then you can seed it by using srand(seedvalue); the seed value can be anything like system time...that'll give you different random numbers every time.

Comment: `randomize` is not a standard C++ function. Which platform are you talking about?