# Random Number Generator mechanism

Tags: c++, random

i had the following problem in my book:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    randomize();
    int Game[]={10,16},P;
    int Turn=random(2)+5;
    for(int T=0;T<20;T++)
       {
           P=random(2);
           cout<<Game[P]+Turn<<"#";
       }
getch();
}
```

The output comes like 16#22#16#16#16#22#....20 times...
Why the output of this always comes either 16# or 22#?? why not 15# or 21#?? i would like to the mechanism of this program. Thanks.
turn=random(2)+5;
if random(2) gives 0 then turn becomes turn=0+5=5 which implies that i should get 10+5=15 and 16+5=21 along with 16 and 22 but i m not getting them.

We got the above question in our computer science theory exam and we were to chose the correct answer(i.e it generates 16 and 22) but how will i am going to know that it will generate only 16 and 22. As i explained above 15 and 21 are also possible..

Comment: What does `randomize()` do?

Comment: This code won’t compile on a modern C++ compiler (and was never valid C++ code!) which leads me to believe that you seriously need to upgrade your working environment.

Comment: i used turbo c++ for a quick compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Turn` is only randomized once - at the beginning of the loop. If you move the assignment of `Turn` into your loop, you should get `15` and `21` also:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    randomize();
    int Game[]={10,16},P;
    int Turn;
    for(int T=0;T<20;T++)
       {
           P=random(2);
           Turn=random(2)+5;
           cout<<Game[P]+Turn<<"#";
       }
    getch();
}
```

Also, as said by others, if you want the output to differ between runs, you will need to seed your random number generator, for instance by calling `srand()` with a [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed). For instance:

```
#include <time.h>
(...)
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: int Turn=random(2)+5;   if random(2) gives out zero then value of turn becomes(turn=0+5) 5..then i should get 15 and 21 also..but i m not getting it!

Comment: Yes, but as your random generator is not seeded, you'll always get the same value from run to run. Seed it with a different value (for instance by using `time(NULL)`), and you should see a difference. However, without moving the assignment of `Turn`, you'll always get runs that contain either 16 and 22 or 15 and 21.

Comment: That's what I said. Seed your generator.

Comment: you said "you'll always get runs that contain either 16 and 22 or 15 and 21" i m only getting 16 and 22(i ran the program again and again and i m still running it ) combination of 15 or 21 never comes can you tell me why. i dont thing seeding is a problem

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps:

The seed for the random number generator is not set.

If you call srand(time(NULL)) then you will get more random results

[C++ rand() gives same number when running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/c-rand-gives-same-number-when-running-process)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a `seed` value that would help get "really" random. mumbers

Answer (score 1):

A computer cannot randomize numbers by itself, it uses a seed for that.

But seed's aren't completely random they just have a specific order, like:

```
1
2
8
5
4
```

These numbers look pretty random but when you run the program the next time you will get:

```
1
2
8
5
4
```

The exact same.

To prevent this we use the time as a seed, time always changes so it will always generate new numbers.

```
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL));  // srand is the function to randomize numbers from a seed, we use 'time' as seed here
```

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naXUIEAIt4U) explains it.