# ' ' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, dev-c++, declare

I'm new and I really can't understand the meaning of "not declared in scope" error. I tried declaring these as functions and also by using "" to show a function but it did not compile and run. Here are the errors:

In function 'int main()':

[Error] 'random' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'sound' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'delay' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'nosound' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'BLINK' was not declared in this scope

[Error] 'textattr' was not declared in this scope

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<iostream>

#include<dos.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int count=50;
    while(count--)
    {
    sound(90*random(10));
    delay(100);
    nosound();
    textattr(random("16")+'a'+BLINK);
    cprintf("KSHITIJ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The function you want is called `rand()` not `random()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Looks like the OP is using some external libraries, given the string input to `random` which is likely a seed, i would say this is part of the lib. Maybe some sort of dos lib?

Comment: Once you get this running you are also going to run into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/c-rand-gives-same-number-when-running-process

Comment: Is this to be used with the `turbo c` compiler? Just stop it, use GCC, ... please.

Comment: It is a **string** type that **contains one character** and not actually a single character so `"a"` instead of `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have Turbo C++ code from back in the 1990's. The last version of Turbo C++ was released before standardized C++, so it's missing stuff and does other stuff somewhat oddly. It also contains a large bundle of its own libraries that can't be found anywhere else. It's hard to find decent support these days as you're noticing.

> ' ' was not declared in this scope

Is your compiler saying, "This name has not been defined." It's usually a prompt that you've missed a header. In this case you have all the right headers, but they don't contain these Turbo C++-only functions. This means you need to find alternatives that are supported with modern compilers.

`random` can be replaced with [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

```
sound(90*random(10));
delay(100);
nosound();
```

Can be replaced with [the win32 call beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx)

`textattr` and `cprintf` you're probably better off without. That blink will be a pain in the posterior to re-implement in GCC. There might be a win32 call to do all this, but I've never tried it and am at a loss.