# Boost Random Number Not Change

Tags: c++, random, boost, random-seed

I have some problem when generating random number with boost library in CPP. When I try printout random number, the value return same value. Here is my code.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_PARTICLES; i++) {
            boost::random::mt19937 engine(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));                    
            randn = boost::bind(boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>(-2.5, 2.5), engine);                            
            cout << "Random : " << randn() << endl;
        }
```

Comment: You're always using the same seed - try putting the engine out the for loop

Comment: different generator, same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/why-does-rand-yield-the-same-sequence-of-numbers-on-every-run btw I found this by simply typing your title into google, hence the downvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same engine seed every time, and therefore you'll receive the same set of random numbers each and every time. Therefore simply seed the engine outside of the for loop like so:

```
boost::random::mt19937 engine(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));                    
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_PARTICLES; i++) 
{
    randn = boost::bind(boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>(-2.5, 2.5), engine);                            
    cout << "Random : " << randn() << endl;
}
```