# why does my random number generator always start with a '1'?

Tags: c++

```
int number_generator(bool new_id)
{
    if (new_id) 
    { 
        srand(time(NULL));
        int x = 99999 + (rand() % 999999); 
        return x;
    }
    else 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Oops! something went wrong"); 
    }
}
```

This function generates a random 6 digit number given a true argument. I have compiled it many times, and the number it generates always start with a '1'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: Look at the range you're generating over. Also check what `RAND_MAX` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does rand() yield the same sequence of numbers on every run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/why-does-rand-yield-the-same-sequence-of-numbers-on-every-run)

Comment: If you need a number between X and Y consider using [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: `time(NULL)` typically has a resolution of 1 second. If you call `srand` multiple times within 1 second you will receive the same seed and generate the same sequence with `rand`.  Since the function looks like it either reseeds and processes the first number in the sequence or throws an exception, this function's pretty much worthless as a random number generator if called repeatedly and quickly. See [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once) for more details.

Comment: rand() Considered Harmful - Stephan T. Lavavej - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 5):

`rand()` returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. The latter can be as low as 32767. C++ only requires `RAND_MAX` to be at least this large. A C++ implementation could use a larger value, but that is not mandated by the standard.

It is possible (even likely) that your implementation chose the minimum admissible value for `RAND_MAX`, i.e. 32767. If that is the case, your computed value `99999 + (rand() % 999999)` is equal to `99999 + rand()`, hence it lies between `99999` and `99999 + 32767`. This will always start with a digit `1` except for the rather unlikely case where `rand()` is zero, causing the result to be `99999`.

Comment: "It's guaranteed that this value is **at least** 32767" At most it can be more.

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes, I wrote "can be as low as..." to indicate this is a possibility. I edited to stress the point.

Comment: "Can be at most" translates to me "maximum value"

Comment: I think Tony complains about your last sentence. That sentence looks good to me though. It implies that `RAND_MAX` is 32767 (which is the case for Microsoft compiler on Windows).

Comment: Indeed was talking about last sentence. +1 from me now.

Answer (score 0):

[std::rand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and [RAND_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX). That number [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 999999

```
rand() % 999999
```

`rand()` has to return a number in range `[100001, 999998]` to have a `2` as starting digit. There is no guarantee rand() will return something in this interval, check RAND_MAX on your system.

Comment: You could add that there is no guarantee that `rand()` can ever return a number in that interval. The rest is very clear to me. (already +1'd)