# My c++ Random string generator is not working

Tags: c++, random

i have been trying to make program that prints random string out of string array. But it is throwing nothing.

I have chaged random number generator algorythm, but it printed same string every time. So i made test aplication and it doesnt work anymore.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
    int x = min + rand() % max;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    string lmao[] = {"xd", "hahaha",",","fjdskl", "fjdskl", "fjkdsljfkdsl","uuruur","fjdksl"};
    string lastZ = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        int x = sizeof(lmao) / sizeof(int);
        int y = randomNumber(0, x);
        string z = lmao[y];
        if (z == lastZ) {
            cout << "Fail";
        }
        else {
            lastZ = z;
            cout << "Succes";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"...If `rand()` is used before any calls to `srand()`, `rand()` behaves as if it was seeded with `srand(1)`..."_ see [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand)

Comment: Dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/why-does-rand-yield-the-same-sequence-of-numbers-on-every-run. Also I have no clue what `int x = sizeof(lmao) / sizeof(int);` is supposed to do

Comment: @pptaszni `sizeof()` method returns size of array but in bytes, so according to tutorial on w3schools is this supposed to convert it to regular number

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `rand`, use the `<random>` header.
2. If you must use `rand`, seed it with `srand` before hand.

Comment: If you must use the `<random>` header, seed your generator before hand. Switching to the new generators doesn't remove this issue.